# In Spark: MatrixFactorizationModel.scala “recommendProductsForUsers” function takes very long time to complete

Tags: machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, recommendation-engine, data-science

I have 9 nodes cluster and each node has the following configurations,

[image]

[image]

I’m trying to generate recommendations for all the users in MatrixFactorizationModel using '**[recommendProductsForUsers](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/recommendation/MatrixFactorizationModel.scala#L218)**' function. Looks like it takes very long time to complete (eg: For 1 month of data it takes approximately around 34 hours). Is it due to the iteration for multiple times over the matrix?

How can I reduce the execution time?

These are my spark-submit configuration:

> spark-submit --jars $JAR_LOC --class
>   com.collaborativefiltering.CustomerCollaborativeJob --driver-memory 5G
>   --num-executors 7 --executor-cores 2 --executor-memory 20G --master yarn-client cust_rec/cust-rec.jar --period 1month --out /PATH --rank
>   50 --numIterations 2 --lambda 0.25 --alpha 300 --topK 20

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found in MatrixFactorizationModel the recommendProductsForUsers runs through multiple iteration so the computational time is high. Once I started to run my jobs in cloud, I tested the job by increasing the nodes and spark-executors. It actually worked! I was able to run and complete the job within 4 hours.